# VBA Excel - SQL query via ADO returns infinite null recordset

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I finally have my code where it needs to be, executing as intended on my machine and returning the result I expect from a number of SQL servers. Problem is a portion of the code only works on my machine. We are running the Excel spreadsheet with specific credentials, (using run as a different user), however the code below only executes properly on my machine (the machine used to develop the code).

There are four SQL DBs being hit, on four different SQL servers. The first three function as intended on other people's machines when they run this script. The fourth SQL call enters an infinite loop on the while not EOF line. The SQL query returns an infinite recordset of null values, regardless of whether or not the query would have normally returned any data. This does not occur on my machine, but happens on others we have tested. One difference between this call and the others is the connection string. The other servers are connected using the following connection string syntax:

Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=XXXX;Data Source=XXXX;

The SQL query in question (as you can see below) uses this syntax:

Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=XXXX;Database=XXXX;Trusted_Connection=yes;

This connection string is the only one that works with this version of SQL server.

What do you think could cause this query to return an infinite null recordset every time its called on other people's machines, but not on mine?

WE have checked the version of Excel, OS, hardware architecture, patches, access to SQL server, running the SQL query via SSMS, installed SQL related components - even had other people log into my machine and run the Spreadsheet with the necessary credentials. Works on my machine only.

```
    'Variables
    Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command
    Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

    'Open connection
    objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=XXXX;Database=XXXX;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
    objMyConn.Open

    'Set and execute SQL command
    Set objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = objMyConn

    objMyCmd.CommandText = "<Valid SQL Statement>"

    objMyCmd.CommandType = adCmdText

    'Open recordset
    Set objMyRecordset.Source = objMyCmd
    objMyRecordset.Open objMyCmd

    sbuildStr = ""

    While Not objMyRecordset.EOF ' HERE IS WHERE THE PROBLEM LIES ON THE MACHINES OF OTHERS
        strPSTPath = CStr(objMyRecordset("foox"))
        strPSTSize = CStr(objMyRecordset("PSTSize"))
        sbuildStr = sbuildStr & strPSTPath & " - " & strPSTSize & Chr(10) & Chr(13)
        objMyRecordset.MoveNext
    Wend

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WORKBOOK").Cells(i, 11).Value = sbuildStr
```

Comment: If i alter the connection string and remove the "Trusted_Connection=yes;" portion, I receive the same error as those on other machines. Interesting. Looking into this now.

Comment: Do the others have access to the sql server using windows authentication?

Comment: What error handling are you using? Do you have "On Error Resume Next" above this code? Is it possible you are hitting some sort of error which is then resulting in your catching an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

After removing the On Error Resume Next, I was able to receive the specific error code alerting me to the issue. After some research, I found the code wasn't executing on other people's machines because SQL Server Native Client 11 wasn't installed. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction, enderland.